# embed custom widget in pyqt fails with ImportError

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, qt-designer

I have created a layout for my custom widget an created a class in file `src\WidgetStartEndCenterWidth.py`

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class WidgetStartEndCenterWidth(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetStartEndCenterWidth, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        uic.loadUi('widgetStartEndCenterWidth.ui', self)
        self.show()

        self.setupSignalSlots()

    def setupSignalSlots(self):
        self.spinBoxStart.valueChanged.connect(self.onSpinBoxStartValueChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onSpinBoxStartValueChanged(self, value):
        self.spinBoxEnd.setValue(value)
```

I promoted the widget in my MainWindow as `WidgetStartEndCenterWidth` with header file (does this make sence at all?) `WidgetStartEndCenterWidth.h`.

However the execution fails with

```
ImportError: No module named 'WidgetStartEndCenterWidth'
```

I assume that this has to do with my code in directory `src`, but anyway I would like to know how this is supposed to be done in the Qt Designer.

EDIT:
The widget is embedded (or promoted) in the ui of MainWindow. Here is the code of that file, but naturally there is not code of the widget, because all that happens in the Qt Designer...

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)
        self.show()
```

Comment: Your example seems very confused. If the code is supposed to represent a custom widget, then why is it loading a ui file? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please show the code that is trying to **load** the custom widget and also detail the location of that file and how it is related to the location of the custom widget. All you have shown is the custom widget code, which doesn't help diagnose the problem.

Comment: There is not code. I define the widget to be used in the ui file. And I found online no example how to do that right for a pyqt project.